# BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream) returns null when retrieving image from SQLite

Tags: android, arrays, image, sqlite, blob

I have a BLOB type column in my SQLite table, and am saving the byte[] of an image from drawable into it. Now , when retrieving, I am accessing the blob using cursor

```
cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(SQLiteHelper.col_product_image))
```

and then using the following code to display the byte[] retrieved from the above code

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(bb);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but nothing is displayed in the image view because `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);` 
is null.

The value of bb is [91, 66, 64, 52, 51, 54, 102, 51, 53, 51, 48, 0]

Help!

Comment: `bb` ??? What is bb? You should show complete reproducable code.

Comment: `saving the byte[] of an image f` Check how many bytes you put in it and how many you get out to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your binary data is stored incorrectly.

The bytes

```
91, 66, 64, 52, 51, 54, 102, 51, 53, 51, 48, 0
```

map to string

```
[B@436f3530
```

which looks like `toString()` output of a `byte[]`, not the byte array itself.

Additionally, Android sqlite does not work for storing large (2MB or more) binary data such as images. You're better off saving the images to filesystem and just store the path in the database.

Comment: Can you provide me with a reference link?